# Setting up Windows Media Center Plugin Template

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, wix, winapi, windows-media-center

I am beginning a project which involves writing a plugin for Windows Media Center.

All I want to do at the moment is run the sample project which is included by default in the Windows Media Center SDK. There are instructions to do this included with the project and I have followed these step-by-step.

I am able to run the program within Visual Studio using the Debug feature (just a simple app with four buttons which don't do anything), but I have a problem when trying to create an installer so the program can be installed within Windows Media Center.

The instructions tell me to add this line to the 'Post-build event command line' section of my project:

```
"$(ProjectDir)Setup\Build.bat" $(ConfigurationName)
```

When I go to build my solution (as instructed), I get the following error:

```
Error   1   The command "%windir%\eHome\McmlVerifier.exe -verbose
-assemblyredirect:"C:\Users\john\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\MediaCenterApplication1\MediaCenterApplication1\bin\Release" 
-directory:"C:\Users\john\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\MediaCenterApplication1\MediaCenterApplication1\Markup"
REM "C:\Users\john\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\MediaCenterApplication1\MediaCenterApplication1\Setup\Build.cmd" Release
"C:\Users\john\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\MediaCenterApplication1\MediaCenterApplication1\Setup\Build.bat" Release
" exited with code 9009.    MediaCenterApplication1
```

I have chosen to write the plugin in C# and this is my setup at the moment:

```
- Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit
- Microsoft Visual C# Express 2010
- Windows SDK v6.0
- Windows Media Center SDK v7.1
- WiX Toolset v3.7
```

Does anyone have any ideas as to what is going wrong? If not, what would be a recommended forum for WMC developers? The forums I have looked at so far all seem to be very quiet.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I got an exit code 9009 when there was no mcmlverifier.exe in the ehome-folder.

A link I found helpful for developing build.cmd is
http://david.gardiner.net.au/2010/10/writing-media-center-application-in.html

Regards
Chris

Comment: Turned out there was a mistake in my post-build events. Thanks for your help though!